# In Html how do I add a label to input fields within a form?

Tags: html

I have a form that displays four entry fields each on its own line, and each with a label:

```
<form method="get" action="/artist/search">
<table>
<tr>
<td>MusicBrainz Artist Id:</td>
<td><input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistid" id="musicbrainzartistid" value="" placeholder="1584532a-62ed-4cbe-ad95-6def0af7df35"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MusicBrainz Artist Db Id:</td>
<td><input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistdbid" id="musicbrainzartistdbid" value="" placeholder="29283"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Discogs Artist Id:</td>
<td><input type="text"   name="discogsartistid"     id="discogsartistid" placeholder="88711"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Artist Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"   name="artistname"          id="artistname" placeholder="pale saints"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

the trouble is although it looks okay is it is not valid html to have a table within a form and it causes a problem with how the html is rendered after the form (doesnt display a

---

)

So if I take the table and labels out it is now valid html but doesnt look how I want it to do, so how can i add a label to each input field so it looks the same as when using tables

```
    <form method="get" action="/artist/search">
    <input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistid" id="musicbrainzartistid" value="" placeholder="1584532a-62ed-4cbe-ad95-6def0af7df35"/>
    <input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistdbid" id="musicbrainzartistdbid" value="" placeholder="29283"/>
    <input type="text"   name="discogsartistid"     id="discogsartistid" placeholder="88711"/>
    <input type="text"   name="artistname"          id="artistname" placeholder="pale saints"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**Update**
So I took the advise below and used the **label for** tag as this seems to be exactly what it is used for but this put all inputs on one line. I then tried using part of the solution for the other answer and added a css class but that made no difference, adding 
 did put each on a new line bu the problem is that the labels are not aligned.

In CSS file

```
.searchform {
  display: block;
}
```

and in html

```
<form method="get" action="/artist/search">
<div class="searchform">
<label for="musicbrainzartistid">MusicBrainz Artist Id:</label>
<input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistid" id="musicbrainzartistid" value="" placeholder="1584532a-62ed-4cbe-ad95-6def0af7df35"/><br>
<label for="musicbrainzartistdbid">MusicBrainz Artist Db Id:</label>
<input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistdbid" id="musicbrainzartistdbid" value="" placeholder="29283"/><br>
<label for="discogsartistid">Discogs Artist Db Id:</label>
<input type="text"   name="discogsartistid"     id="discogsartistid" placeholder="88711"/><br>
<label for="artistname">Artist Name:</label>
<input type="text"   name="artistname"          id="artistname" placeholder="pale saints"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

**Update 2**

I found that using a **div** removed the html errors, Ive left in the label tag as semantically it makes sense but doesnt see to have any effect on input.

```
<form method="get" action="/artist/search">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="musicbrainzartistid">MusicBrainz Artist Id:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistid" id="musicbrainzartistid" value="" placeholder="1584532a-62ed-4cbe-ad95-6def0af7df35"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="musicbrainzartistdbid">MusicBrainz Artist Db Id:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistdbid" id="musicbrainzartistdbid" value="" placeholder="29283"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="discogsartistid">Discogs Artist Db Id:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="discogsartistid"     id="discogsartistid" placeholder="88711"/><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="artistname">Artist Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="artistname"          id="artistname" placeholder="pale saints"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using a **div** removed the html errors, Ive left in the label tag as semantically it makes sense but doesnt see to have any effect on input.

```
<form method="get" action="/artist/search">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="musicbrainzartistid">MusicBrainz Artist Id:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistid" id="musicbrainzartistid" value="" placeholder="1584532a-62ed-4cbe-ad95-6def0af7df35"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="musicbrainzartistdbid">MusicBrainz Artist Db Id:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistdbid" id="musicbrainzartistdbid" value="" placeholder="29283"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="discogsartistid">Discogs Artist Db Id:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="discogsartistid"     id="discogsartistid" placeholder="88711"/><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="artistname">Artist Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="artistname"          id="artistname" placeholder="pale saints"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Label tag is used to label a particular input. It is a W3C Recommendation.

the id of input should be equal to for of label.

Here is the code

```
<form>
<label for="name">name</label> <input type="text" id="name"><br>
<label for="pass">password</label> <input type="password" id="pass"><br>
</form>
```

See live Example on my tutorial:

http://tutorial.techaltum.com/htmlform.html

Comment: Is there any way to align the rows so each input starts at the same point on the line ?

Comment: The best solution is to create form in side table. Create two columns and repeat rows. No need to add css even.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="musicbrainzartistid" style="display:block;">Label text here <input type="text"   name="musicbrainzartistid" id="musicbrainzartistid" value="" placeholder="1584532a-62ed-4cbe-ad95-6def0af7df35"/></label>
```

This should keep everything in the same line for you

Comment: thanks, that adds the labels - but how do i have one label/field per line with them aligned so that the field all start at the same point (as they would within a table), Ive added my attempt to question

Comment: @PaulTaylor I've amended my answer for you :)

Comment: thanks essentailly the same as other answer now but it doesnt align the rows, however i found keeping the table but wrapping wihtin a div has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want each label/input combo to appear on a separate line, but with each label inline with its corresponding input, all you need to do is wrap your `input` elements within the `label` elements, and give your `label` element a CSS styling of `display: block`.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Foo
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Bar
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Baz
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks I used label for from the other aaswer it seemed more correct, then tried adding a css class as you suggested but it had no effect. But even if I took your solution as is each field is not aligned on the horizontal axis ( would be clearer if you changed one of your labels to a longer word) - any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

With Angular you can just define a placeholder like the following:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Text here" />
```